# How to know when textfield are changed without saving

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

there is some design pattern or best practices to implement the "exit without saving changes" in a form?
In my Android app i've used a boolean isChanged set to false on initialization of the view, then if the user focus a textfield and change the text, i compare the new text with the old one and if the doesn't match i put the boolean to true. On the pressure of "close" button, i check the boolean and if it's true the app asks to user if they wanna really close the view.

Comment: You can do same thing with iOS as well. Check UITextFieldDelegate method.

Comment: Try `- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` delegate method of `UITextField` which will call on each char change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UITextfield Delegate methods in your viewController class.

When user tap on the text field this method gets called

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
  //Set the boolean false here.
 }
```

While user is typing this method gets called.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
        shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
        replacementString:(NSString *)string{
}
```

When user stop typing and keyboard returns then this methods gets called.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
 // Set the boolean true here
}
```

if boolean is true then compare the current value to old value and decide the flow.

```
 if(boolean){
    NSString *currentString = textfield.text;
    if([previousString isEqualToString:currentString])
      NSLog("not edited");
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's true. i've also a editable text field on the form. How can i know if it has been edited?

Comment: Once the boolean is true you can compare the previous and current text value based if they are different then that text filed has been edited. See my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Try use TextfieldDelegate function `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

Comment: yeah, that's true. i've also a editable text field on the form. How can i know if it has been edited?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** UITextFieldDelegate

```
//MARK: - UITextfield Delegate Method -
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    if textField.text == ""
    {
        AppDelegate.sharedInstance().showAlertAction(strTitle: "OK", strMessage: "Please enter keyword for search.")
        { (success) in

        }
    }
    else
    {
        let searchVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchViewController") as! SearchViewController
        searchVC.strSearchVal = SAFESTRING(str: self.txtSearch.text!)
        searchVC.isFromHome = true
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(searchVC, animated: true)
    }
    return true
}
```